# How can I prevent a particular view in my Component from being available as a menu item?

Tags: component, development, menu

My component has a number of views that can/should only be used from within the component, and never appear on the list of Menu Item Types to be added to a menu.

To prevent confusion, how does one prevent a particular view from appearing on that list.  I've tried hiding/renaming what I deemed to be relevant files, but to no avail, so haven't been able to determine which file(s) are actually being used to populate that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be driven by xml files in the `tmpl` folder of the view. So for the `default.php` layout, you typically add a `default.xml` file to the same folder to make that layout available as a menu item.

Don't include the xml file and you should not see it in the options list when adding a menu item.

Comment: ARRGH...got all caught up in the metadata XML in the view folder....that did it, and thanks for the slap in the face to wake me up, lol.

Comment: I'm glad that was it, because otherwise I was going to have no idea...